# Why isn't every element of the spectrum an eigenvalue? (Where is the error in my proof?)

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

My book defines the spectrum like this:

> Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, let $I \in B(H)$ be the identity
>   operator and let $T \in B(H)$. The spectrum of $T$, denoted $\sigma(T)$,
>   is defined to be:
>
> $$\sigma(T)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: T-\lambda I\text{ is not invertible}\}$$

Later there is a lemma that says that all eigenvalues are in the spectrum:

> Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and let $T \in B(H)$. If $\lambda$ is
>   an eigenvalue of T then $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$.

But why does the converse not hold? I mean, if $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$, why is not $\lambda$ and eigenvalue? What is wrong with this proof?:

Let $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$, then $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible. Then there is an $x \in H, x \ne0$ such that $T(x)-\lambda x=0$, if not, only 0 will be sent to 0, and then the operator is invertible. But then we have that $T(x)=\lambda x$, and hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Do you see where the error is?

Comment: The word 'invertible' takes on the context of 'being invertible in $B(H)$'. So that means the inverse has to be defined on all $H$ and must be bounded. Generally speaking--but not always--having an inverse and being invertible are terms to distinguish between these cases. $A \in B(H)$ may have an unbounded inverse, but that would not mean that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thank you, but in a banach space, and hence a hilbert space, if it has an inverse, then the inverse is bounded?

Comment: Even if $T \in B(H)$ is one-to-one, that does not mean that the range is all of $H$. The range may be a proper closed subspace, or it may be a non-closed subspace. If the range of $T$ is not closed, then the inverse is not bounded. This is true for a Banach space or a Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thank you that is very interesting. Is it difficult to prove that?, that is: Let $T\in B(x)$,(or $T:  X\rightarrow Y$, T linear and bounded), and assume T is 1-1, but also assume that $\{y_y=T(x), x \in X\}$ is not closed, then the inverse is not bounded. I tried proving it by using the fact that there must be a sequence in the image converging to a point that is not in the image, but I do not see how to end the proof.

Comment: Suppose $T^{-1}$ is bounded, and let $y$ be in the closure of the range of $T$. Then there exists $\{ y_{n } \} \in TX$ such that $y_{n}\rightarrow y$. Hence, $\{ y_{n} \}$ is Cauchy and, because $T^{-1}$ is bounded, then $\{ T^{-1}y_{n} \}$ is Cauchy and, hence, converges to some $x$. Then, because $T$ is bounded, $\{TT^{-1}y_{n} =y_n \}$ converges to $Tx$, which means $y=Tx$ is in the range of $T$. Essentially, if $T^{-1}$ is bounded, then $X$ and $TX$ are topologically equivalent, which means that $TX$ is complete and, hence, closed.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I once read a text that advised that intuition about and experience with finite dimensional linear algebra is misleading as often as it is helpful when considering infinite dimensional linear algebra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If something is non-invertible, there's two (non-disjoint) possibilities: it fails to be injective, or it fails to be surjective. In finite dimension, these are the same, but in infinite-dimensional spaces, weird things can happen.

If it fails to be injective, there's $x \ne y$ such that $(T - \lambda I)(x) = (T - \lambda I)(y)$. So $(T - \lambda I)(x - y) = 0$, implying $T(x - y) = \lambda (x - y)$, showing that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

But if it fails to be surjective, then we can't do that kind of thing. For example, let $T$ be the "right shift" operator, where sequences are padded on the left with zeroes. Clearly $T - 0I$ has no inverse, but that doesn't mean $0$ is an eigenvalue.

EDIT: After getting some sleep, fixed stupid mistake.

Comment: I think you only meant your final sentence in the case of $\lambda = 0$....

Comment: Isn't it non-surjective for all $\lambda$ though? Or is this related to domains and boundedness?

Comment: I don't see why it would be nonsurjective; to solve $(T-\lambda)f = g$, you can just solve for the leading term $f_0 = -\lambda^{-1} g_0$, and recursively solve for the remaining ones from $f_{n-1} - \lambda f_n = g_n$, and it's not "clear" that the result shouldn't be in the Hilbert space.  On the space of all sequences, we can write the inverse as $S = -\lambda^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (T/\lambda)^{k}$. And I think for $|\lambda| > 1$ it maps square summable to square summable, since $$|(Sf)_n| \leq |\lambda|^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^n |f_{n-k} \lambda^{-k}| \leq \max_k(f_k) |\lambda - 1|^{-1}$$

Comment: Oh right, the leading term will be $-\lambda f_0$, not $-\lambda$...

Answer (score 9):

For finite-dimensional vector spaces, injectivity and surjectivity are equivalent. That's not the case for an arbitrary Hilbert space. The classic examples are the left- and right-shift operators $L, R:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$, given by
\begin{align*}
L(x_1, x_2, \dots) &= (x_2, \dots) \\
R(x_1, x_2, \dots) &= (0, x_1, x_2, \dots).
\end{align*}
The map $L$ is clearly surjective but not injective, and $R$ is clearly injective but not surjective. It's easy to see that $R$ has no eigenvalues, but its spectrum is certainly not empty; in fact, it's the closed unit disk.

Comment: Not the OP, but I have a question anyways: why is the spectrum just the unit disk? Isn't $R - \lambda I$ non-invertible for all $\lambda$?

Comment: @HenrySwanson: No, the spectrum of a (continuous) operator $T$ is always bounded (in fact, compact). If $\lambda > \|T\|$, then $(T - \lambda)^{-1} = -\lambda^{-1} \left(1 + \lambda^{-1} T + \lambda^{-2} T^{-2} + \cdots\right)$. The full computation of $\sigma(L), \sigma(R)$ is done in detail in any introductory textbook on spectral theory (e.g., Barry Simon's book).

Answer (score 3):

$T-\lambda I$ being non-invertible ***does not imply*** there is a non-zero $x$ with $(T-\lambda I)x=0$. That is true when $H$ is finite-dimensional, but not necessarily when $H$ is infinite-dimensional. The classic counterexample is the right-shift operator $R:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Take a look at the [Wikipedia article on the notion of spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)).

Answer (score 3):

Left/right shift operators are the standard examples, but I personally think that the multiplication operator is the easiest way to see that there may be something else in the spectrum besides eigenvalues. Consider a multiplication operator $A_c$ on $\ell^\infty$ ($c\in\ell^\infty$)
$$
(A_c x)_n=c_n x_n.
$$
The inverse if exists is clearly a multiplication by $\frac{1}{c_n}$. So $\lambda I-A_c$ is invertible iff $\frac{1}{\lambda-c_n}$ is bounded.

If $\lambda=c_k$ for some $k$ then $\lambda-c_k=0$ and this $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue (the kernel of $\lambda I-A_c$ contains the sequence $e_k$ with all zeros except identity at this particular $k$). So all $\lambda$ in the range of $c$ are eigenvalues. But it may happen that the image is not closed. For example, if we take $c_n=\arctan(n)$, we can observe that there are two special $\lambda=\pm\pi/2$ - endpoints, i.e. from the *closure of the image* of $c$ - such that the sequence $\lambda-c_n$ is never zero, but nevertheless does not have a **bounded** inverse, so that $\lambda I-A_c$ does not still  have a bounded inverse on $\ell^\infty$.